# How to use ACCPC plugin notepad ++ php autocomplete

Tags: notepad++

I installed ACCPC plugin for my notepad++ but it is not working. PHP class inspector area is empty and there is no any autocompletion.

This is screenshot.
pls click to see http://chscelikcati.com/test/notepad%2B%2B.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the path for php class on where do you want to parse all your php class and be included in notepad++ autocomplete. 
Plugins-->ACCPC-->Settings

[image]

---

Try downloading php class here http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6687-PHP-Serve-files-for-download.html

> Note: php class must be the same with the filename